# Bridging Wifi AP to Ethernet on Ubuntu - NAT and MASQUERADE

Tags: networking, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to set up a wireless access point on Ubuntu 18.04 to forward traffic from a wireless client to a host attached via Ethernet. No kind of internet access is needed, just two sensor components talking to each other.

The setup is:

Host Device (192.168.44.1) -- Ubuntu PC Ethernet port (192.168.44.20) -- Ubuntu PC Wifi AP (192.168.42.1) -- Client (192.168.42.X)

Ultimately, I don't care about the PC, it should just act as a bridge to pipe all packages between the client and the host along.

Where I am currently stuck is: I can ping both the host and the client from my PC. I can ping the PC from the client but cannot ping the host device from the client device. I have the impression that the iptables NAT is the problem and that I need to setup a proper bridge, but I somehow cannot seem to get this done.

Maybe someone here can help me fill in the missing pieces, this is what I have so far:

**/etc/network/interfaces**
adapted from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessAccessPoint

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Connection to host A
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.44.20
netmask 255.255.255.0

# Wireless AP
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
address 192.168.42.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I enabled `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` in sysctl.conf

**iptables:**

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

**dnsmasq.conf**

```
interface=eth0,wlan0
no-dhcp-interface=lo,eth0
dhcp-range=192.168.42.20,192.168.42.254,255.255.255.0,12h
```

**hostapd.conf**

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=someTestID
hw_mode=g
channel=1
macaddr_acl=0
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=TKIP
wpa_passphrase=thisIsMyPassPhrase
```

Comment: Everything looks fine - dnsmasq gateway, DNS and the FORWARD rule - check your DNS and gatway on the client machine. Dnsmasq might not pick the gateway and DNS up automatically - add dhcp-option=3,192.168.42.1 and option=6,1.1.1.1. If docker is running on this machine, it sets the FORWARD policy to REJECT. I'm not sure if your FORWARD firewall rule is enough, you can check if it works if you manually run: sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT. Then, a last point: if you can add a route of 192.168.42.0/24 via 192.168.44.20 on your router, you don't need to do NAT and can skip the masquerade rule.

Answer (score 0):

Some things that aren't explicitly set, that might be missing are:

**systemd-resolved**

This service might be interfering with `dnsmasq`. Run `ps auxf|grep dnsmasq` and see if the running instance is running with your config file - or if there is no running instance, it might be blocked because port 53 is occupied. Either disable `systemd-resolved` or tell `dnsmasq` to not bind to port 53.

**DHCP Gateway (Option 3), and DNS (Option 6) for `dnsmasq`**

Check your DNS and gateway on the client machine. `dnsmasq` might not pick the gateway and DNS up automatically - add dhcp-option=3,192.168.42.1 and option=6,1.1.1.1.

**Other `iptables rules**

You can run `sudo iptables -nvxL` and `sudo iptables -t nat -nvxL` to see if you have another firewall program such as `ipfw` running, that might be interfering with your firewall rules. Either move your config over to that, change the order of precedence, or disable it.

**`iptables` `FORWARD` rule**

Then, a last point: if you're doing NAT you don't need the `FORWARD` rule.

If however you can add a route of 192.168.42.0/24 via 192.168.44.20 on your router, you don't need to do NAT and can skip the masquerade rule - in which case you do need the forward rule - but likely only if your run `docker` on this machine as it sets the `FORWARD` policy to `REJECT`.

You can of course test any iteration live, by just issuing `sudo iptables ...` commands. You can go even further by disabling Network-Manager and systemd.reslolved and run `hostapd` and `dnsmasq` in foreground / debugging mode in different terminals or under screen so it will be easy to see what's amiss live.